# VBA erro 13 Tipos incompatíveis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6

Boa tarde,Gostaria de saber o motivo de não estar dando certo este código, aparecendo o erro 13 de tipos incompatíveis:

```vb
Dim W As Worksheet

Dim Linha As Long

Dim Ultima_linha As Long

Set W = Sheets("CMK")

Ultima_linha = W.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With W

For Linha = Ultima_linha To 2 Step -1

If Cells(Linha, "Z") = "#N/D" Then  >>>>>>>>>>>>>> NESTA LINHA AQUI ESTA O ERRO

.Rows(Linha).Delete

End If

Next Linha

End With
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

pelo que testei aqui, o erro ocorre quando voce tem qualquer tipo de dado diferente de numero. Voce criou a sua variavel Linha como tipo Long, porem na celula que ela itera é de tipo diferente de Long.
Ha  a possibilidade de disponibilizar parte da planilha ou uma foto dela?

Answer (score -2):

Erro está no z

Cells(Linha, "Z")

Você precisa colocar o número da coluna e não a letra.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).